# Ruby regular expression for sequence with specified start and end

Tags: ruby, regex, bioinformatics, sequences

I have this string:

```
mRNA = "gcgagcgagcaugacgcauguactugacaugguuuaaggccgauuagugaaugugcagacgcgcauaguggcgagcuaaaaacat"
```

I want to upcase subsequences out of this given sequence. A subsequence should start with `aug` and should end with either `uaa`, `uag` or `uga`. 
When I use the following regular expression in combination with `gsub!`:

`mRNA.gsub!(/(aug.*uaa)|(aug.*uag)|(aug.*uga)/, &:upcase)`

it results in

`gcgagcgagcAUGACGCAUGUACTUGACAUGGUUUAAGGCCGAUUAGUGAAUGUGCAGACGCGCAUAGUGGCGAGCUAAaaacat`

I don’t understand why it upcases one whole chunk instead of giving me two subsequences like this:
`gcgagcgagcAUGACGCAUGUACTUGACAUGGUUUAAggccgauuagugaAUGUGCAGACGCGCAUAGuggcgagcuaaaaacat`

What regular expression can I use to achieve this?

Comment: Just use `aug.*?(?:uaa|uag|uga)` or even `aug.*?(?:u(?:a[ag]|ga))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.*` operator is known as "greedy," which means it will grab up as many characters as it can while still matching the pattern.

To grab the smallest possible number of characters, use the "non-greedy" operator, `.*?`.

Modifying your original regex:

```
mRNA.gsub!(/(aug.*?uaa)|(aug.*?uag)|(aug.*?uga)/, &:upcase)
```

There are certainly smaller regexes that will do the job, though. Using @stribizhev's suggestion:

```
mRNA.gsub!(/aug.*?(?:uaa|uag|uga)/, &:upcase)
```

Comment: You forgot the `?` in your second sentence.